# Back end service end point suspension in wso2 esb 4.9.0

Tags: wso2-esb

We are seeing very peculiar issue in our WSO2 ESB servers. 10% of the time we are seeing some of the back end service end points are getting suspended and we are seeing end point suspension messages in wso2 carbon logs. But the end pointing is working fine. Is there a way to trouble shoot end point suspension issues in WSo2 ESB 4.9.0

Comment: Normally you would see an error in the wso2carbon.log with the endpoint suspension indicating the reason why the endpoint is suspended (timeout, service not available etc.) Perhaps you can update the question with your error message?

Comment: WARN EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : UpdateCustomerDataEndPoint- current suspend duration is : 1000ms - Next retry after : Fri Aug 12 15:58:42 UTC 2016.........We are not seeing any reason for the end points suspension

Comment: Hi Chaps, does anybody experienced the above issue.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if this issue is still current. I'd say get as much information as possible: enable wire logging (configuration->logging->synapse.transport.http.wire) etc. There should be information/logging in there that will shed some light on the issues that you are having.